# c++ using the remove method, which contains a dynamic file name

Tags: c++

I'm doing a parking project and I want to enter a license plate number and delete the file after I've done what I need to do when I'm trying to get the car back. I tried a method for this. But the file cannot be deleted... If you can help I'd appreciate it.

```
cout<<"\t\t\t\t\tLutfen aracinizin plakasini giriniz(Arada bosluk olmadan): ";
cin>>plaka;

ifstream plakaOkuma("C:\\otoparkDB\\araclar\\"+plaka+".txt");
if(plakaOkuma.is_open()){
     string plakalar[1];
     string isim[1];
     int saat[1];
     while(plakaOkuma){
        plakaOkuma>>plaka[0]>>isim[0]>>saat[0];
     }
     ifstream saatlikFiyatOku("C:\\otoparkDB\\saatlikUcret.txt");
     string satir = "";

     if ( saatlikFiyatOku.is_open() ){

     while ( getline(saatlikFiyatOku, satir) ){
  
     }

    saatlikFiyatOku.close();
    }
    cout<<"\t\t\t\t\tAraciniz getirilmistir. Odeyeceginiz Tutar = "<<saat[0]*std::stoi(satir)<<endl;
    string adres = "C:\\otoparkDB\\araclar\\"+plakalar[0]+".txt";


    if(remove(adres.c_str()==0){
    cout<<"Dosya silindi";
    }else{
    cout<<"Dosya silinemedi";
    }
```

I try a lot of things but I couldn't come to a conclusion. I try int status too.

A file is created with the license plate name for each vehicle in the system. Also, you want to delete the file after the process is complete when you import the file. But the plate, which I dynamically adjust when I use the plaka variable, does not work. I also got an error when I tried to use the data I received directly from the user instead of plakalar[0]. I'm creating a file for each vehicle, including the license plate name and finally how many hours it will stay. plakalar [0] are exactly the same plate in short. I also printed the address as a string. But the address is correct. It's not just about deleting the file. I'm waiting for your help.

Comment: Please provide a minimal, reproducible example, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example I would also appreciate translating variable names and comments into English. What you need to delete a file is C++17 and the `filesystem` library, see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem

Comment: You are trying to `remove()` the file while `plakaOkuma` still has the file open. Have you tried calling `plakaOkuma.close()` before calling `remove()`?